# Multiple permissions and ask again on denial

Tags: android, android-permissions

I want to make an app which asks user for two permissions- READ_CALL_LOG and READ_CONTACTS. Now if the user denies READ_CALL_LOG then it should show a warning which should have a button that asks the user to grant permission again. When that button is clicked the user is asked again to grant READ_CALL_LOG permission. When the user grants READ_CALL_LOG permission he is taken to READ_CONTACTS permission. If he denies READ_CONTACTS permission then again it should show a warning which should have a button that asks the user to grant permission again. When that button is clicked the user is asked again to grant READ_CONTACTS permission. I don't want the user to be navigated to Settings if he denies. I have tried this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /*if(((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)&&(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED))||((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)&&(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)))
    requestPermission();*/

    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
    {
        requestCallLogsPermission();
    }

    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
    {
        requestContactPermission();
    }

}

private void requestCallLogsPermission()
{
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        Dexter.withActivity(MainActivity.this).withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG).withListener(new PermissionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Call Logs Permission is granted !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //if((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)||ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                requestContactPermission();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response)
            {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Permissions");
                    builder.setMessage("Permission is required");
                    builder.setCancelable(false);
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Understood, I am ready to give the permissions required", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                        {
                            requestCallLogsPermission();
                        }
                    }).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {
                token.continuePermissionRequest();
            }
        }).check();
    }
}

private void requestContactPermission()
{
    Dexter.withActivity(MainActivity.this).withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS).withListener(new PermissionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Read Contacts Permission is granted !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Permissions");
                builder.setMessage("Permission is required");
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Understood, I am ready to give the permissions required", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        requestCallLogsPermission();
                    }
                }).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {
                token.continuePermissionRequest();
            }
        }).check();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can try this method:

1.) Setting up permissions:

```
String[] permissions = {
        android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA
}; // Use the permission you need
```

2.) -Check and request if not already permitted:

```
onCreate() {
    if (!checkPermissions()){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, 1);
    }
}

private boolean checkPermissions() {
    for (String permission: permissions){
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

3.) Check for denial status and keep asking till all permissions are granted:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    boolean allGranted = true;

    for (int result: grantResults){
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
            allGranted = false;
        }
    }

    if (!allGranted){
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) ||
                ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
        {
            // Here do whatever you want once the user denies
            final String[] mPermissions = permissions;

            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Alert!");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Please allow the permissions!");
            alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((MainActivity.this), mPermissions, 1);
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG, "PERMANENTLY DENIED");

            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Alert!");
            alertDialog.setMessage("All permissions are necessary for app to run. Goto settings and grant them.");
            alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS, Uri.parse("package:" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)));
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            alertDialog.show();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You are taking the user to Settings if he denies. I want to show that Permission dialog box again if the user denies. Do you know how to do that? If so could you kindly tell me.

Comment: Once the result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED, you cannot show the dialog boxes again.

Comment: In my code I could show the READ_CALL_LOG dialog box again but not the READ_CONTACTS dialog box. Could you kindly tell me how can I show the READ_CONTACTS dialog box again?

Comment: I actually don't want to navigate the user to Settings. Could you tell me a way to show the Permission dialog boxes again if the user denies?

Comment: My code doesn't navigate to settings when the user denies. It only navigates when the user selects DO NOT ASK AGAIN

Comment: Oh Ok then I apologize for my mistake. I will now try your code and let you know.

Comment: Yash Krishnan your code works great but could you tell me how to show an AlertDialog which contains a button which says "Please allow the permissions" when the user denies to give the permissions. Then when that button is clicked the user is again asked to grant permissions by those Permission dialog boxes.